# What is the maximum value with set.seed()?

Tags: r

I am working on medium size data set, say with 9000 observations sampled from a large data set with 100,000 observations.

Can I use the following `set.seed()` function to guarantee I get exactly the same subset every time?

```
set.seed(10000)
```

And what is the maximum value I can use with set.seed()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `?set.seed` documentation:

> *seed*     a single value, interpreted as an integer, or NULL (see
>   ‘Details’).

So the maximum value will be the maximum integer allowed:

```
.Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
```

An easy test:

```
set.seed(2147483647)
set.seed(2147483648)
```

> Error in set.seed(2147483648) : supplied seed is not a valid integer
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In set.seed(2147483648) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365167/do-i-have-to-cancel-an-answer-that-has-been-accepted-that-has-arrived-simultaneo/365168#365168

Answer (score 6):

Why is this of interest to you? Usually you should set a seed only once and the number passed to it should be irrelevant.

Anyway:

```
help("set.seed")
```

> seed:  a single value, interpreted as an integer, or NULL (see
>   ‘Details’).

```
set.seed(.Machine$integer.max)
set.seed(.Machine$integer.max + 1)
#Error in set.seed(.Machine$integer.max + 1) : 
#  supplied seed is not a valid integer
#In addition: Warning message:
#In set.seed(.Machine$integer.max + 1) :
#  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

.Machine$integer.max
#[1] 2147483647
```

Comment: You need to set the seed before each sample if you want the same sample each time

Comment: @germcd That's not correct. The sequence of random numbers is always the same starting from the same seed. It's actually a bad practice to set a new seed for each random number because that decreases the randomness.

Comment: the OP said that he wants the same subset each time, which means setting the seed before each sample.

Comment: There might be some miscommunication here. OP's request only makes some sense if they intend to draw many samples each with its own `set.seed`. Something like `for(i in 1:n) {set.seed(i); x[i] <- rnorm(1)}`. That is not something they should do. If you need the same sample from each draw in one and the same R session, you should just store that sample. If you need the same sample in different R sessions, you still need only one seed.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is some miscommunication.
I assumed that the op is sampling multiple times in the same session and getting different samples each time.

Comment: apologies, I took the wrong meaning from "set a seed only once"